# angular-cli.json missing (not hidden)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm starting an Angular course and immediately I've noticed my `angular-cli.json` file is missing. I've tried Googling the issue, and the only responses I've found on Stack Overflow or anywhere else are saying that the file is hidden. I've looked at all my hidden files and it's still not there. I've created a new project and it's still not there.

I'm sort of at a loss on what to do. I don't want to just generate my own because I want to figure out why when I'm creating my new apps the file is never being created. I have an `angular.json` file, but it looks different than the one presented in the course.

I believe I'm running Angular 5 if that helps.

Comment: @ashfaq.p ya sorry, I accepted it. Maybe you can help me though, because this whole change really messes with the lecture I'm watching. 

The syntax of the angular-cli.json file for installing bootstrap is 

`"styles": [ "../node_modules/bootstrap/etc...", "styles.css"]`

an array, while the syntax of the new file is:

`"styles": [ { "input": "src/styles.css" } ],`

an array of objects. What is the proper way to load bootstrap now?

Comment: If you are following a tutorial, i would recommend to switch to the previous stable version of angular-cli. Once this new angular-cli stable version is released, there will be migration guide which you can use to upgrade later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular-cli.json has been replaced with angular.json

You can check this in the release notes:[Release notes for angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases)

In order to follow the tutorial, i would recommend to switch to the cli version used in that tutorial, and switch to latest version later on once you have better understanding.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected that might be the case, but I was really confused why that wasn't coming up in my searches. I even searched the two file names together... Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for some more support?? Bcoz I see that you unaccepted again

Comment: No, sorry, I accepted it, but my browser was showing it unaccepted for some reason after I made an edit, so I clicked it again.